# MapKit annotation .png transparency not working

Tags: swift, annotations, png, mapkit

I have been using the MapKit .png annotations for a while now without any issues. For some reason the transparency just started showing a white transparent color, and I can't figure out what settings I changed (fyi, this started after I created a container but I have no reason to believe the two are related).